# Ethereum does not show up after switching hard drive

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I just bought a new pc with also a new hard drive. I downloaded the whole blockchain and imported the Key into Etherum Wallet. But it still doesn't show me my ETH.

Etherscan saying to me that my ETH is there: https://etherscan.io/address/0x277a43260499e6045e0791171441d57d5d16c574
But my Wallet says my Balance is 0:[image: Wallet]
Searching for a solution for like 4 hours. But didn't find anything :(
please, Help!

Comment: From your screenshot it seems it it not completely synchronized. Also make sure you have selected mainnet and not testnet.

Comment: Was it you who just asked for help on IRC and then quit? Anyway, I'd suggest letting Mist sync (it should display 100% on the upper bar), and rechecking it.

Comment: Yea because nobody answered :( And ok i will do it. Will write if it worked or not

Answer (score 1):

If you're on mist or parity, just open your json file in your wallets folder on the old hard drive with myetherwallet and pull from there. You can also use your private key if you have it txt. Let me know if it works with a micro tip to digitalcurrencysolution.eth from the wallet.

Comment: I took the keystore file from the old harddrive and put it into Account -> Import Accounts. But still 0 ETH . I got the Blockchain synced. I got the ETH like 1 Month ago but they still dont show up. But i got my ETH Account on ETH Wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Wait until you're done syncing with the network.

Also, you may need to import your account. Go to accounts -> Import accounts.

Comment: I did this already. My Network got synced but it still dont shows me my balance. Im on the right Account !